# Generating 8 digit random number in matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I generate 8 digit random number in matlab from **10000000** to **99999999**?

I am trying using `rand` function but the problem is, that it only produces 4 digit numbers.
Also I want the result in a format like **87322343** and not **6.4 * 1.0e7**.

Comment: format is not working....correctly

Comment: Please elaborate. What's not working? What do you get and what do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
r = rand * (99999999 - 10000000) + 10000000
```

Comment: Check out [`format`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/format.html), for instance `format longG`

Comment: Shouldn't the result be an integer? `rand` will give you decimals

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a relatively recent version of MATLAB, there's the [RANDI](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) function which is designed to do exactly this, slightly more simply than @Vakh's answer:

```
randi([10000000, 99999999])
```